# show and hide div on click

Tags: jquery, cakephp, html

I have two divs in my rightbar and I want to display one at a time using show/hide anchor tag but I'm unable to do this as I'm using cakephp. Please help me in achieving this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            document.getElementById('dsearch').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#showhidetarget').hide();

                $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
                    $('#showhidetarget').toggle(400);           
                });
            });     
         </script>    
    </head>        
    <body>
        <script src="/app/webroot/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
        <a id="showhidetrigger" href="/hawaii/tests/dsearch/">Detailed Search</a>
        <div id="showhidetarget"></div>
    </body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Use Jquery toggle method to do that.

Comment: @Ankit Really? You're suggesting the OP to use a technique that he is already trying to use... Please post this as an answer so that I can give you a minus point for it.

Answer (score 2):

try loading jQuery before you call `$document.ready()`

```
<script src="/app/webroot/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {      
  [...]
```

Comment: i have to show my second div on the same page after i click below on written anchor tag of first div and it get displayed on same page.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should put the first script tag after the script tag in which you have included jquery.. this way jquery will be loaded first then the code that is dependent on jquery

```
<script src="/app/webroot/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('dsearch').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showhidetarget').hide();

        $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
        $('#showhidetarget').toggle(400);

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2B5jk/)**

I think your code is working , you just did not have any content in your div.